# admin-ajax return error 400 for Chrome/Edge but not Firefox

Tags: ajax, browser-compatibility

I have a bug with an Ajax request but it works on Firefox.
You can test it clicking [here](https://www.passerellepouremploi.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=getH4ACustomPostTypeByAjax&data%5Bh4a-list-post-status%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-view-mode%5D=card&data%5Bh4a-list-post-type%5D=formation&data%5Bh4a-list-spec-cat%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-cat%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-order%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-orderby%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-meta-key%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-posts-per-page%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-pagination%5D=false&is_count=true)

For Edge/Chrome I got a 400 error.

In Edge I got this error :

> HTTP400: INCORRECT REQUEST - the request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.

What could be the problem in my request ?

Request : `https://www.passerellepouremploi.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=getH4ACustomPostTypeByAjax&data%5Bh4a-list-post-status%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-view-mode%5D=card&data%5Bh4a-list-post-type%5D=formation&data%5Bh4a-list-spec-cat%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-cat%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-order%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-orderby%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-meta-key%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-posts-per-page%5D=false&data%5Bh4a-list-pagination%5D=false&is_count=true`

Why it works for Firefox but not for others browsers ?

Comment: I'm getting the error in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, so I don't think it's a browser issue.  Question; are you logged into WP with one browser but not the other?

Comment: @TonyDjukic Sorry, I did a test. It works for all browsers but only when you are logged in. So thanks for your notice which could help me a lot. I was logged in on Firefox, not for Chrome ;)

Comment: Fantastic.  There’s two different actions for AJAX execution, one for everyone and another for logged in users only.

Comment: Yes, I know my problem was fixed.`wp_ajax_nopriv` was wrapped by `is_admin()`. That could not work ^^. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem fixed !
The problem was not due to a browser matter.
`wp_ajax_nopriv_myfunction` was wrapped by `is_admin()`. That could not work.
I was logged in in Firefox and not in Chrome that´s why I thought it was a browser matter.